# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. impellerc stdout: impellerc stderr:

Tags: flutter, runtime-error

After taking a 10-day break and returning to Android Studio to update my code, I encountered the following error:

Target debug_android_application failed: ShaderCompilerException: Shader compilation of "D:\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\shaders\ink_sparkle.frag" to "D:\Flutter project\newsAPP\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag" failed with exit code -1073741819.
impellerc stdout:

impellerc stderr:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Despite attempting several common fixes like flutter upgrade, flutter clean, and flutter pub get, I'm still facing this error in all my old Flutter projects. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully run my Flutter projects again.